# Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables message on boot plus "Couldn't write '0' to 'vm/dirty_bytes': Invalid argument" after further investigation

Tags: boot, kernel, systemd

As on the tin, I have a seemingly-harmless but still annoying 'Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables' message on boot. SO I of course went ahead and
`systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service` and got this:

Oh, and I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 with i3 as my WM.

```
systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-12 18:08:38 PDT; 18min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
           man:sysctl.d(5)
 Main PID: 352 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Aug 12 18:08:38 agartha systemd-sysctl[352]: Couldn't write '0' to 'vm/dirty_background_bytes': Invalid argument
Aug 12 18:08:38 agartha systemd-sysctl[352]: Couldn't write '0' to 'vm/dirty_bytes': Invalid argument
Aug 12 18:08:38 agartha systemd-sysctl[352]: Couldn't write '6' to 'kernel/rr_interval', ignoring: No such file or directory
Aug 12 18:08:38 agartha systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 12 18:08:38 agartha systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 12 18:08:38 agartha systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.
```

Not sure where to begin with this. I don't really see how dirty-bytes has anything to do with any of it.

Comment: You need some context starting with your OS.

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu with i3 as my WM.